# ¿Cómo copiar un datagridview y pasarlo a otro windows form para posteriormente modificarlo sin afectar el primero?

Tags: c#, gridview

Ante todo buen dia, deseo hacer lo siguiente:

1.- Copiar un datagridview (completo) a otro windows form para poder hacer calculos en este segundo datagridview sin afectar el "original".

2.- Una ves realizado los calculos que los valores que se tengan en "x" columna se remplazen por los resultados que vaya a obtener.
He aqui un ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En Form1 tengo el datagridview que deseo copiar al Form2. Quiero que al presionar Calculate el contenido de la columna "CWS_E" se vea afectada dependiendo del % que se coloque (sin afectar el primer datagridview).

Comment: Y pq no lo puedes hacer? no entiendo el problema.

Comment: El problema es que no se como hacer lo que pregunte, por eso pregunte.

Answer (score 2):

Para pasar un DataGridView entero de un formulario a otro puedes hacer esto:

En el Form1:

```
Form2 frm = new Form2(dataGridView1);
frm.ShowDialog();
```

En el Form2 (el que recibe los datos):

```
public Form2(DataGridView dataGridView2)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   dataGridView1.DataSource = dataGridView2.DataSource;            
}
```

Así de sencillo.

Answer (score 0):

cuando haces la consulta en la base de datos, guardas los datos en una tabla y usas esa tabla para llenar cada uno de tus datagridview.

```
        DataTable tabla = new DataTable();
```

Generas tu query y haces la conexion y ejecutas lo siguente...

```
         SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select, conexion);
         adapter.Fill(tabla);
```

y finalmente llenas tus datagridview...

```
         dataGridView1.DataSource = tabla;
          dataGridView2.DataSource = tabla;
```

Espero que esto te ayude, Saludos...

Answer (score -1):

Puedes intentar lo siguiente:

1. La consulta inicial que haces a la base de datos la almacenas en una lista de objetos, esa lista la asignas al **Grid1**.
2. La lista obtenida, la asignas a un `ViewState` o `Session` (esto en caso de que necesites la lista en otro form o en otro evento del formulario).
3. Ahora a la lista almacenada en el `ViewState` o `Session` le modificas los valores que deseas.
4. La nueva lista modificada, la asignas al **Grid2**.

Espero esta idea te sirva.